# How to install laser_scan_matcher in ros indigo

Tags: ros, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I want to install  'laser_scan_matcher' to generate a 2D map from laser scan using gmapping  in ros. someone please help me install this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224979/how-to-install--laser_scan_matcher-in-ros-indigo/) by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sudo apt-get intall ros-<DISTRO>-laser-scan-matcher`

This is released in `indigo` and `jade`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-01-25**:
when I run this command getting an error as "Unable to fetch some archives".could you please help me to solve this problem.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-01-25**:
This is not a ROS problem.

Did you follow the installation instructions on the ROS wiki?
Do you have a working internet connection?
Does `sudo apt-get update` work?

**Comment by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on 2016-02-01**:
i successfully installed this package.But when i run this i'm getting error `[ WARN] [1454319056.922967304, 1282836401.577617803]: Error in scan matching icp_loop: failed: after trimming, only 29 correspondences. icp: ICP failed for some reason.` please help me..

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-02-01**:
@David John That's another issue. If this answer solved your issue please mark it as the right answer, then open a new question.